# How do I override warnings being treated as errors?

Tags: makefile

This is a problem that I've faced multiple times before. I download a project and type `make`, but it won't compile because warnings are being treated as errors. I want to override this and I don't care about the risks. I also don't want to hunt through the source code to look for every flag. So how do I get projects to compile using `make` without warnings being treated as errors on the command line?

Comment: You need to squash the warnings which may have nothing to do with make, have you tried adding `--disable-werror` to the `configure` step?

Comment: I am afraid there is no one silver bullet for all cases, definitely not at the scope of **make**. If you can narrow your question, e.g. to Linux and gcc, this could lead to something.

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for **make -k** - continue build after fail?

Comment: @AlexCohn I don't know. It's just a real bitch and something developers never offer an option to disable. `make` coordinates all of this stuff, so why can't it be used to override certain things?

Comment: No, this setting is not for make, it's compiler/linker/ *etc* responsibility. Different compilers and other tools use different flags and arguments to treat all or some warnings as errors. On the level of **make**, you can control the flow of commands, but not the commands themselves.